# How use Printf in ma proj

Tags: java

I’m new in Java. I want use printf to print a double number. When I use println, it work correctly. But use either `System.out.printf("%.2d\n" + s.avrage);` or `System.out.printf("%.2f\n" + s.avrage);` a `java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException` occurred.

Comment: Pass the `double` as a separate argument and use `f`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I use System.out.printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730978/how-do-i-use-system-out-printf)

Comment: Change to `System.out.printf("%.2f\n" , s.avrage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your attempt,

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n" + s.avrage);
```

Is you are using a `+` which results in `String` concatenation, instead of passing the second (expected) argument to `printf`. You wanted something like,

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", s.avrage); // <-- comma, not plus
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
    float f = 12.0f;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", f);
```