# New to Java -> Method Issues

Tags: java, methods, call

Pretty sure that I'm missing something fairly obvious here, but I've only been at it a few days. Any help would be much appreciated. I managed to get my class with methods I would like to use to compile, by my main method I was planning link all my results to is getting an error. It says my actual arguments and formal are different. I assume I didn't connect them to the other class or something, but I'm kind of lost. Thanks again!

```
public class SphereAndCone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calc calc1 = new Calc();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the radius?");
        // set sphere/cone radius
        double r = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is the height?");
        // set sphere/cone height
        double h = input.nextDouble();
        // print results while calling on methods
        System.out.printf("Sphere Volume: %3f16" + calc1.sphereVolume());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Sphere Surface: %3f16" + calc1.sphereSurface());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Cone Volume: %3f16" + calc1.coneVolume());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Cone Surface: %3f16" + calc1.coneSurface());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste the exact exception.

Comment: Im getting:                                                                 System.out.print
f("Sphere Surface: %3f16" + calc1.sphereSurface(r));

                                 ^
  required: double,double
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors

Comment: Try using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18732497/2958086). You should be providing 2 (or more, if you have multiple formatted values) arguments to printf, not one. Likely you want to replace the `+` with `,`

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll check that out and give it a try :)

Comment: Yes, you need to use a comma (`','`) instead of a plus (`'+'`).

Comment: `System.out.printf("Sphere Volume: %3f16" + calc1.sphereVolume());` will do the exact same thing as `System.out.printf("Sphere Volume: %3f164.188790204786385");` or something similar.  I.e. the string representation of the volume becomes part of the format string.

Comment: The way my code works right now (or atleast I hope it does) is the user inputs the radius and height. The radius and height are used in formula from a method from another class in the same folder, and then I'm calling to them when I am printing. I seem to be getting the same error. Do I need to do anything to connect my arguments to my other class other than call the method I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.out.printf()` method has the following signature `(String, Object...)` (according to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)).

Now lets go to your code:

```
System.out.printf("Sphere Volume: %3f16" + calc1.sphereVolume());
```

The `+` sign concatenates the two values. The result will be a `String` because the first argument is a `String`. So lets assume that `calc1.sphereVolume()` returns `1.0`. The VM will convert the `1.0` float value to `String` and you will get the newly create "Sphere Volume: %3f161.00000000000000" `String`. When the JVM tries to execute the `printf` method it sees that there is a placeholder (the "%3f16") and it searched in the varagrs (the `Objec...` parameter). It sees that there is no varargs an throws an exception. So basically this is what happens :)

Hope this was helpful :)